# IntelliJ Maven/Gradle Proxy isnt working

Tags: android, maven, intellij-idea, proxy, gradle

I setup a Android Gradle Application with Robolectric.

I used this [tutorial](http://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/all-in-together-android-studio-gradle-and-robolectric/).

It seems working will. I tried to run a test and I got this messages:

```
Downloading: org/robolectric/android-all/4.3_r2-robolectric-0/android-all-4.3_r2-robolectric-0.pom from repository sonatype at https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/
Error transferring file: Connection refused: connect
[WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.robolectric:android-all:pom:4.3_r2-robolectric-0' from repository sonatype (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/): Error transferring file: Connection refused: connect
Downloading: org/robolectric/android-all/4.3_r2-robolectric-0/android-all-4.3_r2-robolectric-0.pom from repository central at http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
Error transferring file: Connection refused: connect
[WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.robolectric:android-all:pom:4.3_r2-robolectric-0' from repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Error transferring file: Connection refused: connect
Downloading: org/json/json/20080701/json-20080701.pom from repository sonatype at https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/
Error transferring file: Connection refused: connect
[WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.json:json:pom:20080701' from repository sonatype (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/): Error transferring file: Connection refused: connect
Downloading: org/json/json/20080701/json-20080701.pom from repository central at http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
Error transferring file: Connection refused: connect
[WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.json:json:pom:20080701' from repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Error transferring file: Connection refused: connect
Downloading: org/ccil/cowan/tagsoup/tagsoup/1.2/tagsoup-1.2.pom from repository sonatype at https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/
Error transferring file: Connection refused: connect
[WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup:tagsoup:pom:1.2' from repository sonatype (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/): Error transferring file: Connection refused: connect
Downloading: org/ccil/cowan/tagsoup/tagsoup/1.2/tagsoup-1.2.pom from repository central at http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
Error transferring file: Connection refused: connect
[WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup:tagsoup:pom:1.2' from repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Error transferring file: Connection refused: connect
Downloading: org/ccil/cowan/tagsoup/tagsoup/1.2/tagsoup-1.2.jar from repository sonatype at https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/
Downloading: org/robolectric/android-all/4.3_r2-robolectric-0/android-all-4.3_r2-robolectric-0.jar from repository sonatype at https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/
Downloading: org/json/json/20080701/json-20080701.jar from repository sonatype at https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/
Error transferring file: Connection refused: connect
Error transferring file: Connection refused: connect
[WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.json:json:jar:20080701' from repository sonatype (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/): Error transferring file: Connection refused: connect
[WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup:tagsoup:jar:1.2' from repository sonatype (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/): Error transferring file: Connection refused: connect
Downloading: org/json/json/20080701/json-20080701.jar from repository central at http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
Downloading: org/ccil/cowan/tagsoup/tagsoup/1.2/tagsoup-1.2.jar from repository central at http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
Error transferring file: Connection refused: connect
[WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.robolectric:android-all:jar:4.3_r2-robolectric-0' from repository sonatype (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/): Error transferring file: Connection refused: connect
Downloading: org/robolectric/android-all/4.3_r2-robolectric-0/android-all-4.3_r2-robolectric-0.jar from repository central at http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
Error transferring file: Connection refused: connect
[WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup:tagsoup:jar:1.2' from repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Error transferring file: Connection refused: connect
Error transferring file: Connection refused: connect
Error transferring file: Connection refused: connect
[WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.robolectric:android-all:jar:4.3_r2-robolectric-0' from repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Error transferring file: Connection refused: connect
[WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.json:json:jar:20080701' from repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Error transferring file: Connection refused: connect
```

It seems that Maven cannot connect to any repo.

I configured a proxy in my `settings.xml`, so it SHOULD work.

Any idea?

Comment: In IntelliJ Settings -> Maven -> Repositories 
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 is listed and updated today. It took a long time for indexing.. but there is no error or anything. So its indexed -> Connection was successfully for that.

I just dont get it.

Comment: Can you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I used the gradle wrapper provided by IntelliJ. I edited the settings.xml of me installed version of Gradle.

I changed the used gradle distribution to my local installed one and wow. It works. :)

Comment: Not sure I understood what was the problem, and how did you fix it. Can you elaborate more about the changes you made in order to get this working? I'm stuck with the same problem: defining proxies in `%M2_HOME%\settings.xml` does not have any effect. And I'm also using gradle wrapper, provided by intellij

Comment: It seems that the settings.xml only comes into play if you use a own installation of Gradle. The provided version of gradle, so the built-in-version, doesnt support settings.xml. Please correct me if I'm wrong.